# Simple Spring Memcached - how to add objects without any expiration

Tags: java, spring, caching, simple-spring-memcached

I am using `SSMCache` to store some objects in my application. I am adding the `SSMCache` object to my `CacheManager` like below :

```
@Bean
@Override
public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    Set<SSMCache> ssmCacheSet = new HashSet<>();
    try {
        ssmCacheSet.add(new SSMCache(getMyCache(),
                PropertyManager.getIntProperty("memcached.interval", 14400), true));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error creating cache manager", e);
    }

    SSMCacheManager ssmCacheManager = new SSMCacheManager();
    ssmCacheManager.setCaches(ssmCacheSet);
    return ssmCacheManager;
}
```

I want to know how to **NOT** specify the cache expiration time in order to make my cache available at all times ie. I do not want my cache to expire at all.

I went through the official documentation for `Simple Spring Memcached` but could not find on how to specify the value for a non expiring cache.

I think using a value of `0` will make the cache not expire at all, but I just want to make sure from a documentation or wiki where it is specified. Also I went through the constructors of `SSMCache` and could not find one which does not have expiration parameter.

Please help me on how to create the cache without an expiration time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, **0** should notify memcached to not expire this key. This doesn't mean that the key will be forever in cache because it still can be removed from cache due to [eviction](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/wiki/UserInternals#when-are-items-evicted).

If you notice that SSM does not honor **0** please report a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the source code in Github repository. You can search "never expire" keyword in repository and you will get the files having lines like below. For example [UpdateSingleCache.java](https://github.com/ragnor/simple-spring-memcached/blob/f203e1ecd564d4a001b630bbacd49abeece41b9d/simple-spring-memcached/src/main/java/com/google/code/ssm/api/UpdateSingleCache.java) has following detail in comments.

> Also note: a value of 0 means the given value should never expire. The value is still susceptible to purging by
>        memcached for space and LRU (least recently used) considerations.